# fabric/invoke, follow the process stdout

Tags: python, paramiko, fabric

I'm trying to run "tail -f something" via fabric, follow its output until it completes and do some processing on each line.

From the docs it looks like I need to pass `watchers=[my_watcher]` to [`run`](https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Runner.run) and pass a subclass `StreamWatcher`

...but I'm not sure how exactly do that. Or is there a simpler way?